# Monero OpenAlias vs Boolberry blockchain aliasing system

Tags: openalias, boolberry, miner-generated-aliasing

How does Monero OpenAlias compare with the Boolberry blockchain aliasing system?

Is the main difference that a domain name is needed for Monero and mining an available alias is required for Boolberry?

What are the other primary differences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BBR aliasing system has many problems, being linked to your address what happens if you lose your private key? There is no way to recover your alias that you could have shared with your friends and family, there is also another problem with the variants, you will run out of simple aliases at some point and it will starting becoming confusing (Alice1, Alice2, Alice3, therealAlice...) at some point its simpler to have a personal address book with Alice's BBR address next to her name. [OpenAlias](https://openalias.org/) does not requires mining, its a simple system that requires only a [few extra settings](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/2uv214/what_is_openalias/) in your Domain Name Registrar and you could use any cryptocurrency with it even Boolberry. You could maintain any domain and add/remove a Monero address associated with it at any time, all the person sending Monero to you need is the domain name. It already works within the simplewallet through the `transfer` command.

Comment: The answer which states "...BBR aliasing system has many problems, being linked to your address what happens if you lose your private key? ..." is a technically unsound, biased statement and intentionally misleading. It would be the equivalent of saying-- "Public-key cryptography has many problems... what happens if you lose your private key?". Yet we all know this is not a valid argument against use of Public-key cryptography, as evidenced in its general and wide accepted use in society today.

Answer (score 4):

BBR aliasing is unique. An alias remains valid in the blockchain permanently as long as the blockchain is intact. From a security point of view it is very secure as it is hardcoded. This is different from a database relaying system offered by other methods.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Readers might be interested in additional details such as how you can check the availability of BBR aliases and more about the implications of aliases being hardcoded to an address.

Comment: This is actually a good point. So far the only place to check for alias on the network was the official website: http://boolberry.com/state.html But its not updated anymore, in fact it doesn't show the aliases at all, reflecting the state of the boolberry project as a whole.